# How to change an integer to a float point using UNIX command

Tags: regex, linux, unix, awk

I wan t to change all integer in a text file to float point using UNIX command.
For example, "X.Yang,is,a,student,in,USYD,from,2016" to"X.Yang,is,a,student,in,USYD,from,2016.00" I know that sed is cannot working on overlapping substitution. And I thought it might be a good idea to use awk, but I don't know how.
Can some one give me some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i+0 == $i) $i=sprintf("%.2f", $i)} 1' file

X.Yang,is,a,student,in,USYD,from,2016.00
```

`$i+0 == $i` condition checks if that column is a valid number.

Comment: Is 3.14159265 a floating point number or two integers separated with a dot? Is 0x123 an integer? Is 123x an integer? Clarification needed!

Answer (score 0):

Try this example: it is just works for your case. Why not ?

`sed -r 's/([0-9]+)/\1.0/g'`